# How to convert date to datetime to seconds since UNIX epoch in R with lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm noticing this very confusing behavior.

```
library(lubridate)
x = as_date(-25567)
as.integer(as_datetime(x)) # Returns NA
```

How can I get this to return the seconds since (or in this case before) UNIX epoch?

Comment: What is 25567 supposed to mean?

Comment: That is 1900-01-01

Comment: Err, then you a) miss all the leap second etc and b) are possibly runnig into overflow and c) should start with a proper parse.  Answer coming....

Comment: For some reason, `as.numeric(as_datetime(x))` produces the integer I'm looking for. I just don't understand why `as.integer` doesn't. Ah... no big integers in R!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with base R, now that we covered that you really want `as.Date("1970-01-01")`.

```
R> as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 00:00:00")    
[1] "1900-01-01 CST"                       
R> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 00:00:00"))
[1] -2208967200        
R>
```

I vaguely recall some OS-level irritations for dates prior to the epoch. This may fail for you on the world's most commonly used OS but that is not really R's fault...